# How to properly implement Huygen's integral?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, optics, simulations, software

I'm really confused by what's happening ... I'm trying to propagate a beam some distance and compare initial and final intensities.

Lets say the initial electric field is just cos(200x). I then used the Huygen's integral according to this equation to find the final electric field:

[image]

For some reason, I'm getting intensity that is six orders of magnitude higher at one meter away from the origin, which is clearly madness ...

The actual meat of the code is like ten lines, I know that I typed everything in right, which means I must not be understanding some physics...
Could someone please explain what I'm doing wrong?

```
function test

x = sym('x');

zi = 0;                                  % initial position
zf = 1000;                               % final position

c = 3*10^8;                              % speed of light
epsilon = 8.86*10^-12;                   % permittivity of free space
lambda = 1064*10^-9;                     % wavelength
k = 2*pi/lambda;                         % wave number

xmax = 0.02;
inc = 10^-4;
xlist = -xmax:inc:xmax;                  % x-axis range
slit = 2*10^-3;                          % slit length

Ei = zeros(size(xlist));
Ef = zeros(size(xlist));

    function ploti
        for i = 1:length(xlist)
            Ei(i) = Ei(i) + cos(200*xlist(i));
        end
        Ii = 1/2*c*epsilon*arrayfun(@(x)(x.*conj(x)),Ei);
    end

    function plotf
        for i = 1:length(xlist)
            Ef(i) = Ef(i) + sqrt(1i/lambda)*integral(@(x)Ei(i).*exp(-1i*k*sqrt((zf-zi)^2+(xlist(i)-x).^2))/...
                sqrt((zf-zi)^2+(xlist(i)-x).^2).*(1+cos(atan((xlist(i)-x)/(zf - zi))))/2,-slit/2,slit/2);
        end
        If = 1/2*c*epsilon*arrayfun(@(x)(x.*conj(x)),Ef);
    end

ploti
plotf  

plot(xlist,Ii,'b',xlist,If,'r');     % initial and final intensity plots
legend('I initial','I final');       % curve labels
xlabel('x(m)')                       % x-axis label
ylabel('I(W/m^2)')                   % y-axis label

end
```

------------------------- EDIT --------------------------

ok so I think the issue was partially fixed by changing `1i/lambda` to `sqrt(1i/lambda)` as it should have been for a 2D case. Here's what the output looks like now. I'm still a little concerned the intensity profiles look so different and final intensity grows beyond initial the closer it gets to zf = 0. Is it because the initial intensity profile is just of the beam BEFORE the slit, and final is AFTER?

[image]

-------------------------- EDIT 2 ------------------------

Nope. I was told this is wrong still :(
Then I have no idea :( ...

Comment: The formula isn't quite right: there's a vector on the left and a scalar on the right. In addition, in the integrand there must be $(x - x_0)^2$ in the exponent. - Now write $E_0(x_0) \sim \cos kx_0 = (e^{i kx_0} + e^{-i kx_0})/2$, whereupon your integral is just the sum of two Gaussian ones that can be done analytically.

Comment: @TomHeinzl yeah, those are just typos in the equation, sorry. In the code, it actually is (x−x0)2... I think I partially fixed it >.> ... could you see the update and tell me if that looks closer to real life? XD

Comment: You can't expect people here to debug your code. I'd suggest that you understand the physics first before coding. Why does your integral "propagate a beam"? Which type of beam? Propagation through vacuum or a lens etc.? If I take a plane wave such as $\cos(kx - \omega t)$ in vacuum it will stay a plane wave. This suggests that your integral corresponds to propagation through some optical device. Again, for your choice of $E_0$ it can be done analytically, so I'd do it and then try to compare with my code.

Comment: @TomHeinzl, i think it is right actually ... i was just confused by divergence of intensity as zf -> zi, which can be plainly seen from the equation, but it didn't make sense to me physically because if a plane way passes through a slit, immediately after the slit it should still be a plane wave, no? I then read someone that that equation for Huygen's integral only works in paraxial approximation... Approximations make the mathematician in me sad ... But i guess it doesn't really matter because who ever looks at the final intensity that close to the slit.